# Copying Powershell PSCustomObject to array element will pass reference, not value

Tags: arrays, powershell, pscustomobject

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but when copying a PSCustomObject in Powershell to an array element, this is copied by reference.
See this:

```
$body = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
    albumId = $album_id;
    newMediaItems = [PSCustomObject]@()    
} 

$mediaItem = [PSCustomObject]@{
    description = "";
    simpleMediaItem = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        fileName = "";
        uploadToken = "";
        }
}

$mediaItem.description = "Friend of Mickey Mouse"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.fileName = "Goofy.txt"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.uploadToken = "1111"

$body.newMediaItems += $mediaItem.PsObject.Copy()

$mediaItem.description = "Friend of Rocker Duck"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.fileName = "Donald Duck.txt"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.uploadToken = "2222"

$body.newMediaItems +=  $mediaItem.PsObject.Copy()


$body | ConvertTo-Json -depth 4
```

Output:

```
{
  "albumId": null,
  "newMediaItems": [
    {
      "description": "Friend of Mickey Mouse",
      "simpleMediaItem": {
        "fileName": "Donald Duck.txt",
        "uploadToken": "2222"
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "Friend of Rocker Duck",
      "simpleMediaItem": {
        "fileName": "Donald Duck.txt",
        "uploadToken": "2222"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.psobject.Copy()` performs *shallow* (member-wise) cloning of `[pscustomobject]` instances.

Since your `simpleMediaItem` property contains a reference to a *.NET reference type* (which happens to be another `[pscustomobject]` instance), it is the *reference* that is copied, so that both the original `[pscustomobject]` and the clone obtained via `.psobject.Copy()` reference *the very same object*.

For *deep* (recursive) cloning (for which there is no universal solution), you'd have to create a custom implementation.

You can avoid the problem altogether using a custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) definition:

```
class MediaItem {
  [string] $description
  [pscustomobject] $simpleMediaItem = [pscustomobject] @{ 
      fileName = ""
      uploadToken = ""
  }
}
```

Now you can simply use `[MediaItem]::new()` every time you want a new, independent instance.

To put it all together:

```
class MediaItem {
  [string] $description
  [pscustomobject] $simpleMediaItem = [pscustomobject] @{ 
    fileName    = ""
    uploadToken = ""
  }
}

$body = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
  albumId       = $album_id;
  newMediaItems = @()    
} 

# Create a new instance.
$mediaItem = [MediaItem]::new()
$mediaItem.description = "Friend of Mickey Mouse"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.fileName = "Goofy.txt"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.uploadToken = "1111"

$body.newMediaItems += $mediaItem

# Create a new instance.
$mediaItem = [MediaItem]::new()
$mediaItem.description = "Friend of Rocker Duck"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.fileName = "Donald Duck.txt"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.uploadToken = "2222"

$body.newMediaItems += $mediaItem

$body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

Comment: Great comment and solution, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Riccardo; my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is expected, you're only copying the base object. I would also recommend you doing this with *function* or a *class*, it would be much easier and no copying needed.

```
$body = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
    albumId = $album_id;
    newMediaItems = [PSCustomObject]@()    
} 
$mediaItem = [PSCustomObject]@{
    description = "";
    simpleMediaItem = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        fileName = "";
        uploadToken = "";
    }
}
$mediaItem.description = "Friend of Mickey Mouse"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.fileName = "Goofy.txt"
$mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.uploadToken = "1111"

$body.newMediaItems += $mediaItem

$base = $mediaItem.PsObject.Copy()
$child = $mediaItem.simpleMediaItem.PSObject.Copy()

$base.description = "Friend of Rocker Duck"
$child.fileName = "Donald Duck.txt"
$child.uploadToken = "2222"
$base.simpleMediaItem = $child

$body.newMediaItems += $base
```

Comment: How would you do this in a loop?

Comment: @Riccardo I think mklement0's answer covers that

Comment: Thanks for bringing your thoughts here! Upvoted :-)

Comment: @Riccardo np, I was about to start writing the class but he beat me to it lol